# States that password_required? is an undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I installed Devise and OmniAuth according to the rails casts. I understand that they are a little out dated, however it was all working until i tried to just sign up. w/o using my omniauth twitter feature.

The error i get is

```
NoMethodError at /users/sign_up undefined method `password_required?'
```

in my user.rb

```
1 def password_required?
2  super && provider.blank?
3 end
```

I tried to move it to the UserHelper file. didn't work.

here is my erb file

```
1  <h2> Sign up </h2>
2  <%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name,
3   url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
4
5  <%= f.error_notification %>
6
7  <div class="form-inputs">
8    <%= f.input :email, required: true, autofocus: true %>
9    <% if password_required?  %>
10    <%= f.input :password, required: true %>
11    <%= f.input :password_confirmation, required: true %>
12  <% end  %>  
13 </div>
14
14 <div class="form-actions">
16   <%= f.button :submit, "Sign up" %>
17 </div>
18  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call this method from resource instance:

```
<% if resource.password_required?  %>
```

Comment: its funny how one word can make a difference. Thank you so much @chumakoff